# When window is resized in Chrome JkMegaMenu drop downs moving left

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm using the JKmegamenu plugin to implement a megamenu on a website I'm working on. It works and looks nice, however when the web browser(Chrome) window is resized the drop down divs move left.

I got the JavaScript code from this link. You can check in Chrome:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jkmegamenu.shtml

Please try to help me to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line in menu script automatically aligns your menu wrt window's width: line No 29

```
var menuleft=($(window).width()-(megamenu.offsetx-$(document).scrollLeft())>megamenu.actualwidth)? megamenu.offsetx : megamenu.offsetx-megamenu.actualwidth+megamenu.anchorwidth
```

if you want it to stick to the left of that anchor then replace above line with:

```
var menuleft=megamenu.$anchorobj.offset().left;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the positioning from the top was also off, though not as noticable, so I replaced:

```
var menutop=megamenu.offsety+megamenu.anchorheight  //get y coord of menu
```

with

```
var totop=megamenu.$anchorobj.offset().top; 
var menutop=totop+megamenu.anchorheight
```